# ¿Cómo puedo enviar una página de prueba de la impresora utilizando Delphi?

Tags: delphi, impresión

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto dónde se necesita imprimir una página de prueba a una impresora particular. La página de prueba de la impresora debe ser la misma que imprime Windows cuándo se envía desde *propiedades de la impresora* -> *imprimir página de prueba*.

¿cómo puedo hacerlo con Delphi?

[How can I send to print a Test Page to a printer using Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199227/how-can-send-to-print-a-test-page-to-a-printer-using-delphi/5199410#5199410)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este trozo de código imprimirá la página de prueba a la impresora por defecto:

```
uses ShellAPI, printers;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Device, Driver, Port: Array [0..255] of Char;
  hDevMode: THandle;
begin
  Printer.GetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, hDevmode);
  ShInvokePrinterCommand(handle, PRINTACTION_TESTPAGE, Device, nil, true );
end;
```

Resultado:
[image: Printer test page]

Si quieres enviar la página de prueba a otra impresora, envía el nombre de la misma en el parámetro `Device`, y en ese caso puedes ahorrarte la llamada a Printer.GetPrinter, por ejemplo:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShInvokePrinterCommand(handle, PRINTACTION_TESTPAGE, 'MiImpresora', nil, True);
end;
```